# What is the origin of the -a in words like "collega, advena"?

Tags: etymology, morphology, suffixes, declinatio-prima

There are a couple of masculine (or common) nouns of the first declension. Some are from masculine Greek -ês, like *poeta, nauta*. But others, like *collega, advena, parricida, scriba, incola, agricola, indigena, conviva, auriga, assecla/assecula* are natively Latin. What is the origin of this native *-a*? And can the same root be observed in other endings / forms? Judging by *parricida*, there might be a conexion with masculine *-as*. But is that also the case with other words?

Lewis & Short:

> parrĭcīda (pārĭcīda; old collat. form of the nom. sing. PARICID**AS**, Fragm. XII. Tab. ap. Fest. s. v. parrici, p. 221 Müll.)

Another interesting word is **druida*, "druid", which, however, [seems to be of Celtic origin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%AAne#%C3%89tymologie_et_diff%C3%A9rentes_appellations). It does show that the Romans were quite used to masculine words of the first declension.

Comment: The native Latin *-a* seems to come from verbs: *-cida < caedere, collega < colligere, advena < advenire, traha < trahere*, and so on. The Greek [*poeta*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/439/79) has a verb behind it, but *nauta* doesn't seem to.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Perhaps so. But the verbal stem on -i- does not appear to be present in *advena*, so at least it isn't a direct derivation from he ordinary verb. // The Greek words are, I think, unrelated: it is clear where that -a came from.

Comment: The derivative *-a* might not take the present stem as such. The *i* is only in the present stem of *advenire*. I agree that the Greek words are unrelated; the origins of the two examples are clear enough and quite different from the Latin examples.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: True! If they're old formations, they need not be derived from existing temporal/supine stems. As to *traha*, that one's feminine, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's feminine. It's also the only one on my list that doesn't mean a person. Perhaps they were originally all feminine or the non-humans became feminine by analogy to the first declension.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: It's possible! I was hoping for an answer like that. I would be inclined to suspect a conexion with the masculine suffix *-as*, though, but who knows? As to *traha*, you feel it's similar or related because it is derived from a plain verbal root and it ends on *-a*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is generally believed is that

> "The Italic "1st declension" continues PIE feminine formations ("ā-stems") built with an invariable suffix *-eh<sub>2</sub>(-)" ([Vine 2017:](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110523874/9783110523874-003/9783110523874-003.xml) 755)

cf. Beekes 2011 proposal of an ablauting suffix *eh<sub>2</sub>(-) ~ *-h<sub>2</sub>(-)).

Weiss notes that

> "Masculine nouns of the first declension that we find in Latin are largely personalizations of feminine abstracts" (p. 228),

cf. Klingenschmitt 1992 ("Die lateinische Nominalflexion" in O. Pangal and Th. Krisch (eds.), *Latein und Indogermanisch: Akten des Kolloquiums der Indogermanischen Gesellschaft, Salzburg 23. - 26. September 1986*. Innsbruck, 1992):

"Das Vorhandensein maskuliner *ā*-Stämme stellt eine nach grundsprachliche Neuerung dar. Die maskulinen *ā*-Stämme sind, soweit es sich um einheimische Elemente handelt,  durch metonymischen Gebrauch ursprünglicher Feminina sekundär entstanden. So sind etwa * *skrīfā*- 'das Schreiben' oder alte Determinativkomposita wie * *agro-k<sup>w</sup>olā*- 'Feldbau' zur Bezeichnung der die betreffende Tätigkeit ausübenden Person verwendet worden, was dann eine Maskulinisierung dieser Wörter nach sich zog (lat. *scrība* m. 'Schreiber', *agricola* m. 'Bauer')" (p. 89).

Clackson adds that such nouns are mostly **compound** ([Clackson 2011:](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781444343397.ch8/summary) 106), cf. *advena*, *agricola*, *conviva*, *incola*, or *indigena*. The only simplex native masculine noun is *scriba*. [will rewrite this section later, based on the discussion in Leumann 1977; this is more complicated than it seems]

Ernout 1952/2014 calls them **formes archaïques** (p. 12).

Leumann explains it with Greek influence, cf. "muss man die ersten lat. mask. Komposita auf -a als Nachbildung griechischer Muster auffasen" (p. 281). For *collega*, he proposes an ad-hoc explanation (*lega, from legatus)

Some other cases:

1. Greek loans: *nauta*, *poeta*;
2. Etruscan names: *Caecina*, *Perpenna* (*Perperna*), *Sisenna*, *Spurinna* (Leumann 1977: 279);
3. loans of uncertain origin: *verna* 'house-slave;'
4. Etruscan loans: *cacula* 'servant', *sculna* 'arbitrator', *verpa* 'male member' ([Baldi 1999:](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110807110/9783110807110.300b/9783110807110.300b.xml) 317).

Comment: In addition to *scriba*, there is *traha*. It's not a person, but I thought it's morphologically the same.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta my dictionary (Castiglioni) says traha is feminine.

Comment: Highly useful comparison of references! Would *Catilina* also be Etruscan? I think so? // I also wonder about the conexion with *-as* as mentioned in L&S: *pārĭcīda; old collat. form of the nom. sing. PARICIDAS, Fragm. XII. Tab. ap. Fest. s. v. parrici, p. 221 Müll.* (added to my updated question above).